# Dcevm with maven

Tags: maven, aem, hotswap, dcevm

I was in a process to set up dcevm on my laptop so that code can be deployed to server without running `mvn clean install` for every server side change I make. And I managed it working for me using jre.

But now if I try to build project manually  using maven command `mvn clean install`. It gives me error saying you are using jre instead of jdk.

So is there any way by which, I can use both the option to build and deploy server side code. Manually using maven command and automatically using dcevm??

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to the JDK bin and not the JRE bin?

Comment: It is pointing to JRE

Answer (score 1):

Building AEM projects using Maven will only work with a compatible Java JDK. Java JRE will not work so you must set your JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK folder and not the JRE folder.